# Hide close button in android Search View

Tags: android, searchview

I have implemented an android search view.When the search view gains focus, the close button [x] at the right shows up.How to hide close button in android search view

Comment: I think you can't do that, for that you must user custom sercview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your theme like this:

**For < v21:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/AppTheme.WidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WidgetTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**For v21 and above:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Also check [this](https://philio.me/styling-the-searchview-with-appcompat-v21/) for more customization.

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you use support libraries, the first part of @Anton advice may not work, so it would be sufficient to write in values/styles.xml something like:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewStyleAfterV21</item>
</style>
...
<style name="SearchViewStyleAfterV21" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [set 'x' button programicaly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54202350/5985886) ?

> In case you want do it programicaly, put a piece of code that hides "x" button in `onQueryTextListener`:

```
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            searchViewIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your XML layout file:

```
app:closeIcon="@android:color/transparent"
```

Then disable the button:

```
ImageView btnClose = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
btnClose.setEnabled(false);
```