# how to remove close icon from edittext in searchview

Tags: android, searchview

I am trying to customize the searchview. 
i wanted to get rid of close icon in searchview. what i have done so far?

```
int closeId =android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn;
ImageView close = (ImageView)mSearchView.findViewById(closeId);
close.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

this code removes the close icon. But as soon as i start typing in editText it appears back in.
How to permanently get rid of it?

close icon is remove when expanded searchView

[image]

it comes back in when i type in editText.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tried this?: [Hide close button in android Search View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262503/hide-close-button-in-android-search-view)

Change your theme like this:

**For < v21:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/AppTheme.WidgetTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.WidgetTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**For v21 and above:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.SearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
    <item name="closeIcon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Also check [this](https://philio.me/styling-the-searchview-with-appcompat-v21/) for more customization.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want do it programicaly, put a piece of code that hides "x" button in `onQueryTextListener`:

```
   searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            ImageView searchViewIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
            searchViewIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to your SearchView xml layout file :

```
app:closeIcon="@android:color/transparent"
```

Then disable the close button :

```
ImageView btnClose = searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
btnClose.setEnabled(false);
```